# how to simplify $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus

can you help me please to simplify this?

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)\right)$

i tried to do like this...

$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{2-x}}$ , $\frac{0.5^{-0.5}}{\sqrt{2-x}}$ , $\left(\frac{0.5^{-0.5}\cdot \sqrt{2-x}-\left(1^{0.5}\cdot 0.5\:\left(2-x\right)^{-0.5}\cdot \left(-1\right)\right)\:}{2-x}\right)$ , $\frac{0.5^{-0.5}\cdot \sqrt{2-x}-\:\left(-0.5\left(2-x\right)^{-0.5}\right)}{2-x}$ , $\frac{\frac{1}{0.5^{0.5}}\cdot \sqrt{2-x}-\left(-0.5\:\cdot \:\left(\frac{1}{\left(2-x\right)^{0.5}}\right)\right)}{2-x}$ , $\frac{\frac{\left(2-x\right)^{0.5}}{0.5^{0.5}}+\frac{2}{\left(2-x\right)^{0.5}}}{2-x}$

I really dont know if this is the correct way... i need to get somehow (ln(x)−1)(ln(x)+3) and i dont know how.

Comment: Do not blindly differentitate, you should do a couple of manipulations before taking the derivative. Do you see you can write the following?
$$\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)=\frac{-1}{2}\ln(2-x)$$
Taking the derivative of above is easier.

Comment: oh thank you! i just answered this question with $ln\frac{a}{b}^c=cln\frac{a}{b}\:and\:ln\frac{a}{b}\:=\:lna\:-\:lnb$ rules!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\text{ln}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)$$
Simplify by using identity $\text{log}(a^b)=b\text{log}(a)\,.$
Factor out the constant $\frac{1}{2}$.
You now have:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\text{ln}\left(\frac{1}{2-x}\right)\,\,.$$

Use chain rule then you get $$\begin{align} -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(2-x)}{2-x} &= -\frac{-\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(x)+0\right)}{2(2-x)} \\&= \frac{1}{4-2x} \,\,, \end{align}$$
which is the answer.

Comment: Welcome on Math.SE ! To get a nice start, learn about how to properly format your answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [MahtJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). Basic are simple and you will need only a few minutes to get them. It's very simple for basic expressions like these ones. It will considerably improve your ability to communicate here. Then edit your answer.

Comment: I have typesetted your answer @Rudi. When it is approved, look over it and let me know if any content has been lost to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\text{log}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right) &= -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\text{log}(2-x) \\=& \frac{1}{2(2-x)}\end{align}$$
where $\text{log}$ denotes the natural logarithm.

Comment: I think you forgot a $\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$ in the right-hand side of the line.

Comment: No, I don't think so @V. Rossetto

Comment: or maybe I need one more coffee... Sorry, I overlooked it, somehow.

Comment: No problem, @V. Rossetto